# Receiving `ERROR in multi styles.css` when trying to run ng test

Tags: angular, karma-runner, ionic4

After upgrading Angular to 7.2.6, I can successfully build using `ng build` but when I run `ng test` I get the following Error. I've tried adjusting the path to `styles.css` in my `angular.json` file, and still receive the same error. I'm at a loss for what is happening. I'm using Ionic 4 as well.

```
ERROR in multi ./styles.css
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '/Users/zsoflin/Documents/GitHub/Layer/styles.css' in '/Users/zsoflin/Documents/GitHub/Layer'
resolve '/Users/zsoflin/Documents/GitHub/Layer/styles.css' in '/Users/zsoflin/Documents/GitHub/Layer'
  using description file: /Users/zsoflin/Documents/GitHub/Layer/package.json (relative path: .)
    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
    using description file: /Users/zsoflin/Documents/GitHub/Layer/package.json (relative path: ./styles.css)
      no extension
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        /Users/zsoflin/Documents/GitHub/Layer/styles.css doesn't exist
      .ts
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        /Users/zsoflin/Documents/GitHub/Layer/styles.css.ts doesn't exist
      .tsx
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        /Users/zsoflin/Documents/GitHub/Layer/styles.css.tsx doesn't exist
      .mjs
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        /Users/zsoflin/Documents/GitHub/Layer/styles.css.mjs doesn't exist
      .js
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        /Users/zsoflin/Documents/GitHub/Layer/styles.css.js doesn't exist
      as directory
        /Users/zsoflin/Documents/GitHub/Layer/styles.css doesn't exist
[/Users/zsoflin/Documents/GitHub/Layer/styles.css]
[/Users/zsoflin/Documents/GitHub/Layer/styles.css.ts]
[/Users/zsoflin/Documents/GitHub/Layer/styles.css.tsx]
[/Users/zsoflin/Documents/GitHub/Layer/styles.css.mjs]
[/Users/zsoflin/Documents/GitHub/Layer/styles.css.js]
 @ multi ./styles.css styles[0]
```

My `package.json` dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^7.2.6",
    "@angular/cdk": "^7.3.3",
    "@angular/common": "^7.2.6",
    "@angular/core": "^7.2.6",
    "@angular/fire": "^5.1.1",
    "@angular/forms": "^7.2.6",
    "@angular/http": "^7.2.6",
    "@angular/material": "^7.3.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^7.2.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^7.2.6",
    "@angular/pwa": "^0.13.1",
    "@angular/router": "^7.2.6",
    "@angular/service-worker": "^7.2.6",
    "@capacitor/android": "^1.0.0-beta.17",
    "@capacitor/cli": "^1.0.0-beta.17",
    "@capacitor/core": "^1.0.0-beta.17",
    "@capacitor/ios": "^1.0.0-beta.17",
    "@firebase/app-types": "^0.3.4",
    "@firebase/messaging": "0.3.4",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^5.0.0-beta.22",
    "@ionic-native/firebase": "^5.2.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "^5.2.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "^5.2.0",
    "@ionic/angular": "^4.0.2",
    "@ionic/ng-toolkit": "1.1.0",
    "@ionic/pro": "^2.0.4",
    "@ionic/schematics-angular": "^1.0.7",
    "@types/stripe": "^5.0.25",
    "angular2-text-mask": "^9.0.0",
    "angular2-uuid": "^1.1.1",
    "angularfire2": "^5.1.1",
    "core-js": "^2.5.3",
    "firebase": "^5.8.4",
    "firebaseui": "^3.5.2",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "ionicons": "^4.5.5",
    "ng-animate": "^0.3.4",
    "ng-pipes": "^0.1.2",
    "ng-stripe-checkout": "^1.0.4",
    "ngx-color": "^2.0.5",
    "ngx-device-detector": "^1.3.5",
    "ngx-papaparse": "^3.0.0",
    "ngx-stripe": "^6.0.0-rc.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.10.0",
    "rxjs": "6.4.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.29"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/architect": "^0.7.5",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.13.3",
    "@angular-devkit/core": "^0.7.5",
    "@angular-devkit/schematics": "^0.7.5",
    "@angular/cli": "^7.3.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "^7.2.6",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^7.2.6",
    "@angular/language-service": "^7.2.6",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.6",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^10.5.8",
    "codelyzer": "^4.4.4",
    "css-loader": "^2.1.0",
    "firebase-tools": "^6.4.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "^3.1.4",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^2.0.4",
    "karma-jasmine": "^2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
    "modules": "^0.4.0",
    "protractor": "^5.4.1",
    "style-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "ts-node": "^7.0.1",
    "tslint": "~5.11.0",
    "typescript": "^3.2.4"
  }
```

My `test config` in `angular.json` file:

```
"test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "src/karma.conf.js",
            "styles": [
              "styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "assets": [
              {
                "glob": "favicon.ico",
                "input": "src/",
                "output": "/"
              },
              {
                "glob": "**/*",
                "input": "src/assets",
                "output": "/assets"
              },
              "src/main-sw.js",
              "src/firebase-messaging-sw.js",
              "src/manifest.webmanifest"
            ]
          }
        },
```

Comment: What are you importing from you styles.css?

Comment: Actually I don't believe I'm importing anything. I removed the file `styles.css` from the styles array and ng test works. the angular.json file has just always contained that file from the start of my Ionic project and I haven't had any errors until now.

Comment: I have exactly same issue. My path for styles.css in test section in angular.json is not correct. I fixed the path, now it works. Thanks for your question!

Answer (score 18):

looks like is trying to get the styles from architect > build > options > styles (angular.json).
just copy the styles to architect > *test* > options > styles and run again the test.
it work for me!

To clarify, make sure in your angular.json file that the styles section in your test section matches your build section (or is at least valid)
ex angular.json:

[image]

Comment: You saved my day! Thank you.

Comment: As the answer says, in my case 'styles' array of 'test' object was different than 'styles' array of 'build' object in angular.json file.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open angular.json file (config old)
2. Go to "test" section
3. Add "scr/styles.css" instead of "style.css" for "styles"

[image]

[image]